# R: Why doesn't the negative index work to create the complement set?

Tags: r, indexing, subset

I am trying to create training, validation, and test data sets. (Before I filter the dataframe into the appropriate data sets, I am trying to create vectors with the list of rows that each data set will contain.
There are 654 observations, and I intend to place 354 in training, and 200 Validation, 100 test.
Here is the code I used:

```
x <- 1:654
train_ind <- sample(x, 354)
rest <- x[-train_ind]
length(rest)
[1] 300
valid <- sample(rest, 200)
length(valid)
[1] 200
test <- rest[-valid]
length(test)
[1] 210
```

I don't understand why the `test` object is 210!
I would think that since `valid` is only length 200, that if I take `rest` (300) and negative index the `valid`, then I will only be left with 100.
I appreciate any input into what I'm doing wrong.
Thank you

Comment: In situations like this I highly suggest trying your process out on a much smaller example. If you make x<-1:20 and make your other sample sizes smaller you can easily print the entire results and not just their lengths. This will help you see where the process stops being what you would expect.

Comment: you sample from `rest` and that vector dose not represent indices but subset of `x`. You should sample like this `sample(seq_along(rest), 200)` if you want to sample indices.

Comment: `x <- 1:654; i <- sample(x); split(i, rep(1:3, c(354, 200, 100)))`

Comment: As an FYI, George Mason University has a very nice tutorial on using tidymodels to build regression workflows: https://www.gmudatamining.com/lesson-10-r-tutorial.html  You can follow along by copying and pasting the code into RStudio.  The tidymodels workflow includes functions to split a data set.  Very nice.

Comment: @det rawr (Dason SteveM) thank you all for great answers/comments!

Comment: So I currently have 3 solutions for splitting the data, and the direct answer to my question is @det

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just shuffle the indices (sampling without replacement) and then get the first few for testing and the others for training.

```r
indices <- sample(seq(20))
test <- indices[1:10]
train <- indices[11:20]

train
#>  [1] 10  8 12  1  7 20 13 18  4 11
test
#>  [1] 19  3 15  2  6  9 16 14 17  5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>